# Shear tensor for Newtonian fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Consider a Newtonian fluid. The shear tensor is defined by:

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\Big) - \frac{1}{3}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v})\delta_{ij}.
\end{equation}

Suppose we consider it on a sphere, i.e. $x_1 = r \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, $x_2 = r \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$ and $x_3 = r \cos(\theta)$. I have a hard time showing $\sigma_{ij}=0$ for this case. I tried to compute e.g.

\begin{equation}
v_1 = \frac{dx_1}{dt} = \dot{r}\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) + \dot{\theta}r \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) - \dot{\phi}r \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) = \frac{\dot{r}}{r}x_1 + \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}x_1 \dot{\theta} - x_2 \dot{\phi}.
\end{equation}

How do you compute e.g. $\partial v_1/\partial x_1$ from this? In particular should be rewrite $r$,$\theta$ etc. back in terms of $\{x_i\}$? And how to deal with the derivative terms?

Is the following true?

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\dot{r}}{r} + \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\dot{\theta},
\end{equation}

or should we also take into account derivatives like $\partial r/\partial x_1$?

Comment: Why don't you use $x_i=\{r,\,\theta,\,\phi\}$?

Comment: Please clarify: Does "Suppose we consider it on a sphere" mean you want to express the tensor components in spherical coordinates or are you thinking of a sphere as a particular domain geometry for a flow problem? Why would $\sigma_{ij}=0$?

Comment: The latter indeed, i.e. sphere as a domain geometry. A spherical collapse problem where we assume the sphere does not rotate

Comment: I.e. I think we have $\mathbf{v} = \dot{r} \mathbf{\hat{r}}$, i.e. $v_r = \dot{r}$. How to proceed with it?

Comment: If $\mathbf v=\dot r\mathbf{\hat r}=v_r\mathbf{\hat r}$, then it is clear $\sigma_{ij}=0$ as $\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}=\mathbf 0$.

Comment: That helps, you just coordinates and velocities as independent right? So for my understanding rotation would give $\mathbf{v} = \dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + r(\dot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{\theta}} + \dot{\phi}\sin(\theta)\hat{\mathbf{\phi}})$ and e.g. $v_\theta = r \dot{\theta}$ so $\partial_r v_\theta = \dot{\theta}$ while $\partial_\theta v_\theta = 0$ ?

Comment: Right, in case the velocity is the full expression, you'd have
$$\frac{\partial(v_r,v_\theta,v_\phi)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
\dot\theta & 0 & 0\\
\dot\phi\sin\theta & r\cos\theta\dot\phi & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Doig the calculations, $\sigma_{ij}\neq 0$, only in the radial velocity case it is $0$.

Comment: Tried but I don't get 0 due to the transformation of the shear tensor to spherical coordinates, could you please make it into an answer?